# yarn add command dosen't install package

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg-v2

I have very simple node project where I'd like to add dotenv package by yarn package manager. I'm working on linux Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. I'm typing command:

```
yarn add dotenv
```

The output is:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "npm/dotenv: Invalid URI \"npm/dotenv\"".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/krzysztofmichalski/projects/dotenv-learning/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

Content of yarn-error.log:

```
Arguments: 
  /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/yarn add dotenv

PATH: 
  /home/krzysztofmichalski/anaconda3/bin:/home/krzysztofmichalski/anaconda3/condabin:/home/krzysztofmichalski/projects/cucumber-gherking-learning/node_modules/bin:vendor/bin:/home/krzysztofmichalski/.symfony/bin:/home/krzysztofmichalski/projects/apache-kafka/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/krzysztofmichalski/projects/dotenv-learning/node_modules/.bin

Yarn version: 
  1.22.17

Node version: 
  17.3.0

Platform: 
  linux x64

Trace: 
  Error: npm/dotenv: Invalid URI "npm/dotenv"
      at Request.module.exports.Request.init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:140971:31)
      at new Request (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:140825:8)
      at request (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:137731:10)
      at RequestManager.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:67081:15)
      at RequestManager.shiftQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:67119:10)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:66788:13
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at new F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:5301:28)
      at RequestManager.request (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:66786:19)
      at NpmRegistry.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:31747:42)

npm manifest: 
  {
    "name": "dotenv-learning",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
    }
  }

yarn manifest: 
  No manifest

Lockfile: 
  No lockfile
```

I don't know why is that. I'm using npm in another projects. Is it caused by mixture of them in operating system?

Comment: It seems you somehow misconfigured the registry as `npm` instead of `https://registry.npmjs.org`.

Comment: What dou you suggest? yarn config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org hasn't helped me :(

Comment: Yes, I have seen this issue before with yarn, you can reinstall the yarn globally, or uninstall and then install. 
`npm install --global yarn`

Comment: It haven't helped me. Still I can see the same error.

Comment: I realized it should be `https://registry.yarnpkg.com` and not `https://registry.npmjs.org`, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Looks that the NPM registry is misconfigured. Try running this command to reset registry URL:

```sh
yarn config set registry "https://registry.yarnpkg.com" -g
```

Comment: It haven't  helped my. Error still occurs.